# when a radio button is in ng-repeat when i click on radio button the div will be enable?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here when i click on radio button the following div should be disable if the checked radio button is equals to sj.But here its not working if i use ng-repeat for radio button same is working if its static.Could any one help me out what is the mistake i have done here?

```
<div ng-app="plunker">
  <div class="wrap" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h1>Hello there!</h1>
    <p>Push the radio buttons to change the content!</p>
    <form> 
      <div ng-repeat="s in color">
      <input id="first" type="radio" name="content" ng-model="content" value="s.name">{{s.name}}
      <br/></div>
    </form>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <p ng-show="content == 'sj'">This is the first content!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.color = [{"name":"sj"},{"name":"asfdsaf"},{"name":"sdfsadf"},{"name":"sdf"}];
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things are missed

1. Change you `ng-model` scope variable to point its parent like `ng-model="$parent.content"` instead of `ng-model="content"`, because ng-repeat creates child scope from current scope.
2. Use `ng-value` instead of `value` attribute for binding scope variable to it.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <div ng-repeat="s in color">
        <input id="first" type="radio" name="content" ng-model="$parent.content" ng-value="s.name">{{s.name}}
        <br/>
    </div>
</form>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/O2jWuENxWydGxS6xGm9M?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

you can check the code in this

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.contentshow=true;
    $scope.color = [{
        "name": "sj"
    }, {
        "name": "asfdsaf"
    }, {
        "name": "sdfsadf"
    }, {
        "name": "sdf"
    }];
    
    $scope.showsj=function(radioshow){
        if(radioshow.name==='sj'){
              $scope.contentshow=false;
        }
        else{
              $scope.contentshow=true;
        }
    };
})
```

```css
.done-true {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker">
    <div class="wrap" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
         <h1>Hello there!</h1>

        <p>Push the radio buttons to change the content!</p>
        <form>
            <div ng-repeat="s in color">
                <input id="first" type="radio" name="content" ng-model="content" value="s.name" ng-click="showsj(s)">{{s.name}}
                <br/>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <p ng-show="contentshow">This is the first content!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```